# On trying to print JasperReports report using Java, the Tomcat Apache Server is shutting down when trying to view the report again

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, struts

I am trying to use *JasperReports* to create reports in my project.

I already have the .jrxml file generated. After that I have created the front end (a form) and on clicking "Submit", I need to print the report. On Clicking "Submit" button, I am calling the below code in my Action class (*Struts 1.2*),

```
if (actionForm.get("hiddenAction").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Submit")) {
    try {
        //DataBase
        connection = ConnectionHelper.getUniqueInstance().getConnectionFromPool();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String report = "E:\\Report\\RP_BI_SUCCESS.jrxml";

        String fromStrDate = "01/12/2013";
        String toStrDate = "25/12/2013";

        parameters.put("I_SPMID", 0);
        parameters.put("I_GATEWAYLKUPID", 0);
        parameters.put("I_FROMDATE", Utilities.convertStringDateToSQLDate(fromStrDate));
        parameters.put("I_TODATE", Utilities.convertStringDateToSQLDate(toStrDate));
        parameters.put("I_MODE", "A");
        try {
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters, connection);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
            jasperPrint = null;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To set this up, I have used *JasperReports 5.5.0* (executable JAR file) in a folder in my project.

Case 1:
When I click on "Submit" button, i am able to get the *JasperViewer* window with the necessary report i wanted. Then if i am closing the report the *Tomcat Apache Server* (*Tomcat Apache V 7.0*) is getting shut down automatically.

Case 2:
But if i am clicking on "Submit" again without closing the previous opened report, then its fine.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Jasper.viewReport(jasperPrint)
```

by

```
JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false, null);
```

jasperViewer.setVisible(true);

It works for me just fine in Tomcat, in Glassfish doesn't.